# Filling up a coordinate list in Python

Tags: python

I have a sorted list of coordinates, e.g.

```
coords = [[19, 52], [20, 52], [24, 52], [25, 52], [20, 53], [22, 53], [20, 54], [21, 54]]
```

I want to fill in the coordinates "in between", such that the resulting list is:

```
result = [[19, 52], [20, 52], [21, 52], [22, 52], [23, 52], [24, 52], [25, 52], [20, 53], [21, 53], [22, 53], [20, 54], [21, 54]]
```

How can I do that? We can assume that the "gap" in the coordinates is always either continuous or zero, as in the case of the last two "tuples" in coords. We are also only dealing with integers here. I have managed to write a function that can do so for exactly 1 y-coordinate:

```
def fillElements(sequence):
    k=0
    while (sequence[k][0]+1) == (sequence[(k+1) % len(sequence)][0]):
        k+=1
    if k == len(sequence):
        return sequence
    else:
        dummy = list(range((sequence[k][0]+1), sequence[k+1][0]))
        for l in range(len(dummy)):
            sequence.append([dummy[l], sequence[0][1]])
        return sequence
```

This function first finds the "break" where coordinates are missing by comparing the x-value of the current element with the x-value of the next; if they are more than 1 apart, there is the break. I also already took care of some edge cases where (i+1) would be outside of the length of the list; instead, it goes back and compares to the first entry. In that case, when the while loop ends, the running index k should be exactly the length of the sequence, and the sequence is returned unchanged. If the running index is smaller than the length of the sequence, it means the break exists. In that case, I create a dummy list that includes all the missing x-values by using range(), with the boundaries being the k-th "tuple", where the loop was broken, +1 because I do not want to have the same x-value twice, and the next element. I then append these values in sublists with the y-coordinate.

However, while this function works, the code is both kind of ugly, and like I said, it only works for one y-coordinate. Solving the latter is the most important part, but if somebody has suggestions to improve this code or use another approach in the first place, please let me know. The ordering of the coordinates  in the resulting list is not important.

e: In case of a "unique y-coordinate", e.g. the "tuple" [20, 51], nothing should be changed, since there is no element "in between".

Comment: What should be the result if the input is `[[1, 3], [3, 5]]`?

Comment: And what should be the result if the input is `[[1, 4], [3, 2]]`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 in that case, the result should be the same as the input. I will edit that into the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to fill in gaps in the `x` co-ordinates, resetting each time the `y` co-ordinate changes.

The following is a Python 3 solution which will do that:

```py
def fill_gaps(coordinates):
    last_x, last_y = None, None

    for x, y in coordinates:
        if y == last_y:
            # Fill in any potential gaps between the last value and us
            yield from ([new_x, y] for new_x in range(last_x + 1, x))

        last_x, last_y = x, y
        yield [x, y]
```

This uses a generator to make the code a bit easier, so if you want a list you will need to wrap the call with `list()` to make that happen:

```py
result = list(fill_gaps(coords))
```

This solution requires the co-ordinates to be sorted as you stated.

Comment: Great, thank you very much! Seems like I need to learn what generators do.